# How to encrypting and decryption the Plugins key's and ID in IOS info.plist file to prevent insecure data for cordova mobile app

Tags: ios, cordova, encryption, cordova-plugins, info.plist

We have developed the Cordova mobile app (Hybrid app) and which is live on App-store and google play-store, if user download the ios app i'e .IPA file if we do the reverse engineering like zip the ipa file and unzip IPA file so anyone can see the all the images and info.plist file's stored keys and id's of plugins which is causing the security thread so how we can encrypt and decrypt the info.plist data in cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

info.plist files are not meant for storing sensitive data like API keys and such, what you can do is to have keys on code and obfuscate your code using solutions like this:

https://github.com/pjebs/Obfuscator-iOS
and https://github.com/Polidea/SiriusObfuscator

other paid solutions exists also.

Comment: Thanks Mosbah , its hybrid app (cordova app) we need the cordova plugin to fallow similar solution by the help of javascript or any alternative solution while preparing the ios builds in XCODE